# How to create the executable from multiple .o files that require external dependencies?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, executable, libs

I need to compile a C++ project which is going to use external libraries and headers from the project for linear programming COIN-OR. It contains three .cpp files that I have successfully compiled into .o files. The main problem I have is what to do next. As all the files are compiled without error, I assume they should at least give me some result.

How can I create the executable files for linux?

I have tried

> gcc myfile.o -o main

It doesn't work, it outputs a very large block of error text.

In case it is needed, this is the Makefile:

```
#
P=farmer
#

EXE=$(P)
OBJS=main-farmer.o model-farmer.o param-farmer.o pm.h

ADDLIBS=-D.
ADDINCFLAGS=-I.

SRCDIR=~/coin-projects

########## 


CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wimplicit -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion
CXXLINKFLAGS=-Wl,--rpath -Wl,/installed/CoinAll/lib
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-03 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wimplicit -Wparentheses -Wsequence-point -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall


COININCDIR=/installed/CoinAll/include/coin

#  COIN-OR libs
COINLIBDIR=/installed/CoinAll/lib

#  Clp
LIBS=-L$(COINLIBDIR) -lCbc -lCgl -lOsiClp -lOsi -lClp -lCoinUtils -lm \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/cgl_addlibs.txt` \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/clp_addlibs.txt` \
`cat $(COINLIBDIR)/coinutils_addlibs.txt` 



CLEANFILES=\
addBits.o addBits \
addColumns.o addColumns \
addRows.o addRows \
decompose.o decompose \
defaults.o defaults \
driver2.o driver2 \
driver.o driver \
driverC.o driverC \
dualCuts.o dualCuts \
ekk.o ekk \
ekk_interface.o ekk_interface \
hello.o hello \
makeDual.o makeDual \
minimum.o minimum \
network.o network \
piece.o piece \
rowColumn.o rowColumn \
sprint2.o sprint2 \
sprint.o sprint \
testBarrier.o testBarrier \
testBasis.o testBasis \
testGub2.o testGub2 \
testGub.o testGub \
testQP.o testQP \
useVolume.o useVolume

# Part 3
#

all: $(EXE)

.SUFFIXES: .cpp .c .o .obj

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    bla=;
    for file in $(OBJS); do bla="$$bla `$(CYGPATH_W) $$file`"; done; \
    $(CXX) $(CXXLINKFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $$bla $(ADDLIBS) $(LIBS)

####
########
############
########
####


clean:
    rm -rf $(CLEANFILES)
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.cpp.obj:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then $(CYGPATH_W) '$<'; else $(CYGPATH_W) '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.c.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then $(CYGPATH_W) '$<'; else $(CYGPATH_W) '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
```

This is the error I'm receiving whenever I try the command
g++ main-farmer.o model-farmer.o param-farmer.o -o main

Error message:

```
model-farmer.o: In function models(double*, double (*) [3], double*, double*, double*, double (*) [3], double (*) [3], double (*)
  [3], double (*) [3][3], double (*) [6][3])':
  model-farmer.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition ofmodels(double*, double () [3], double, double*, double*, double () [3], double () [3], double () [3], double () [3][3], double () [6][3])' main-farmer.o:main-farmer.cpp:(.text+0x60): first defined here param-farmer.o: In function param(double*, double (*) [3], double*,
  double*, double*, double (*) [3], double (*) [3], double (*) [3],
  double (*) [3][3], double (*) [6][3], double*, double*, double*,
  double*, double*, int*, int*, double*, int&)':
  param-farmer.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition ofparam(double, double () [3], double, double*, double*, double () [3], double () [3], double () [3], double () [3][3], double () [6][3], double, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, double*, int&)' main-farmer.o:main-farmer.cpp:(.text+0x590): first defined here main-farmer.o: In function main':
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x16e): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::OsiClpSolverInterface()' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x198): undefined reference to CoinPackedMatrix::CoinPackedMatrix(bool, int const*, int const*,
  double const*, int)' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1cb): undefined
  reference toOsiClpSolverInterface::loadProblem(CoinPackedMatrix const&, double const*, double const*, double const*, double const*, double const*)' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2fc): undefined reference to ClpModel::setOptimizationDirection(double)'
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x32c): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::setInteger(int)' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x340): undefined reference to OsiClpSolverInterface::setInteger(int)'
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x354): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::setInteger(int)' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x361): undefined reference to OsiClpSolverInterface::initialSolve()'
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x36e): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::isProvenPrimalInfeasible() const' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3ab): undefined reference to CoinPackedMatrix::~CoinPackedMatrix()'
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3b8): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::~OsiClpSolverInterface()' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3de): undefined reference to OsiClpSolverInterface::isProvenOptimal() const'
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3f3): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::getObjValue() const' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x44d): undefined reference to OsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const'
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x478): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4a4): undefined reference to OsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const'
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x520): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x551): undefined reference to OsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const'
  main-farmer.o:main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x582): more undefined
  references toOsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const' follow main-farmer.o: In function main':
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x92f): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::branchAndBound()' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x94a): undefined reference to OsiClpSolverInterface::writeMps(char const*, char const*, double)
  const' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x957): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::getObjValue() const' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x96e): undefined reference to OsiClpSolverInterface::isProvenOptimal() const'
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9d6): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::getObjValue() const' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa32): undefined reference to OsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const'
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0xabc): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0xae9): undefined reference to OsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const'
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb16): undefined reference to
  OsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb43): undefined reference to OsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const'
  main-farmer.o:main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb70): more undefined
  references toOsiClpSolverInterface::getColSolution() const' follow main-farmer.o: In function main':
  main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc8f): undefined reference to
  CoinPackedMatrix::~CoinPackedMatrix()' main-farmer.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc9c): undefined reference to `OsiClpSolverInterface::~OsiClpSolverInterface()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This is the error message I'm receiving:

Answer (score 1):

To compile `.c` and link `.o` files you should write

```
gcc FirstFile.o SecondFile.o ... -o main
```

But if you compile `.cpp`, use `g++` instead of `gcc`. 
Files from external libraries you should also write in the list above.

What errors did your command output?